# Transformed Wiener Process

Tags: wiener-measure

How is it that if $W$ is a Wiener process and if we define $\widetilde{W}=W + \frac{\mu - r}{\sigma}t$, then $-\frac{\widetilde{W}}{\sqrt{T}}$ is standard normal?